# SQL query error with ODBC connection in R using Informix driver

Tags: r, informix, rodbc

With functionality from the RODBC package, I have successfully created an ODBC but receive error messages when I try to query the database. I am using the INFORMIX 3.31 32 bit driver (version 3.31.00.10287).

```
channel <- odbcConnect("exampleDSN")
unclass(channel)
[1] 3
attr(,"connection.string")
[1] "DSN=exampleDSN;UID=user;PWD=****;DB=exampleDB;HOST=exampleHOST;SRVR=exampleSRVR;SERV=exampleSERV;PRO=onsoctcp ... (more parameters)"
attr(,"handle_ptr")
<pointer: 0x0264c098>
attr(,"case")
[1] "nochange"
attr(,"id")
[1] 4182
attr(,"believeNRows")
[1] TRUE
attr(,"colQuote")
[1] "\""
attr(,"tabQuote")
[1] "\""
attr(,"interpretDot")
[1] TRUE
attr(,"encoding")
[1] ""
attr(,"rows_at_time")
[1] 100
attr(,"isMySQL")
[1] FALSE
attr(,"call")
odbcDriverConnect(connection = "DSN=exampleDSN")
```

When I try to query and investigate the structure of the returned object, I receive an error message 'chr [1:2] "42000 -201 [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]A syntax error has occurred." ...'

Specifically, I wrote an expression to loop through all tables in the database, retrieve 10 rows, and investigate the structure of the returned object.

```
for (i in 1:153){res <- sqlFetch(channel, sqlTables(channel, tableType="TABLE")$TABLE_NAME[i], max=10); str(res)}
```

Each iteration returns the same error message.  Any ideas where to start?

ADDITIONAL INFO: When I return the object 'res', I receive the following -

```
> res
[1] "42000 -201 [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]A syntax error has occurred."
[2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'SELECT * FROM \"exampleTABLE\"'"
```

Comment: what happens when you query a single table?

Comment: @Chase: Regardless of table, when I query a single table (and assign the query result to 'res') I receive the same error messages as above (except that 'exampleTABLE' is the actual name of the table).

Comment: hmm...have you tried any other functions to retrieve results? Perhaps `sqlQuery(channel, "select top 10 * from exampleTABLE")`?

Comment: @Chase: Your suggestion to use sqlQuery worked.  If you write this suggestion as an answer, I'll accept it as 'the' answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the `sqlQuery()` function in RODBC to retrieve your results. This is the function I use at work and have never had a problem with it:

```
sqlQuery(channel, "select top 10 * from exampleTABLE")
```

You should be able to put all of your queries into a list and iterate through them as you were before:

```
dat <- lapply(queries, function(x) sqlQuery(channel, x))
```

where queries is your list of queries and channel is your open ODBC connection. I guess I should also encourage you to close said connection when your done with `odbcCloseAll()`

Answer (score 2):

The error message you quote is:

```
"[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'SELECT * FROM \"exampleTABLE\"'"
```

Informix only recognizes table names enclosed in double quotes if the environment DELIMIDENT is set in the environment, either of the server or the client (or both).  It doesn't much matter what it is set to; I use `DELIMIDENT=1` when I want delimited identifiers.

How did you create the table in the Informix database?  Unless you created the table with DELIMIDENT set, the table name will not be case sensitive; you do not need the quotes around the table name.

The fact that you're getting error -201 means you've got through the connection process; that is a good start, and simplifies what follows.

I'm not sure whether you're on a Unix machine or a Windows machine - it often helps to indicate that.  On Windows, you might have to set the environment with SETNET32 (an Informix program), or there may be a way to specify the DELIMIDENT in the connect string.  On Unix, you probably set it in your environment and the R software picks it up.  However, there might be problems if you launch R via some sort of menu button or option in a GUI environment; the chances are that the profile is not executed before the R program is.

Comment: I am not the creator of the database tables.  Sorry that I did not specify my OS; it's Windows XP Professional Version 2002.  I actually tried the suggestion of @Chase (using sqlQuery with a SQL string) and it worked.