# RODBC sqlTable error incorrect syntax

Tags: sql, r, rodbc

This bit of code works just fine on R under Windows, but running under Linux Mint 17.1, it produces an error.

```
intcal <- sqlFetch(db, "intercal_samples")
```

Here's the error:

```
[1] "42000 102 [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'intercal_samples'."   
[2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'SELECT * FROM \"intercal_samples\"'"
```

Interestingly, this equivalent code works fine on both systems.

```
intcal <- sqlQuery(db, paste("select * from ", "intercal_samples"))
```

It seems like some sort of quoting/escaping issue, but I can't figure it out. Is this a bug in RODBC, or am I missing something?

Comment: look into this, may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048836/sql-query-error-with-odbc-connection-in-r-using-informix-driver

Comment: Thanks, that question is similar but with more info. Still don't quite get why quoting works differently between systems and commands, but it's clear at least that that's what's causing the trouble. I just switched to using sqlQuery.